# How to process and update large arrays using webgl?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, typed-arrays

I have two large `Uint8Array`. The sizes are: `1024` and `2048`

I would like to update these arrays in each frame.

The `1024` length array would fit into 256 vec4 uniforms, or a 16*16 image. But I don't think, it is the right way to do it.

How to send large arrays from javascript to GLSL?

---

**Edit**

My problem with textures is, that to update the image in each frame, I have to copy the data into an `ImageData` object. Then I have to draw the imageData onto a canvas. And after that, I have to get the dataURL of the canvas, and change the src attribute of the image

Comment: I might be beneficial to share what kind of modifications you are trying to do in javascript. It is possible that those modifications could be done in a pixel shader, resulting in much (much!) better performacne.

Comment: You do *NOT* have to copy your data into an `ImageData`. You can upload typed arrays directly into textures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Textures are the appropriate way to work with large datasets in WebGL. You can store your data in a 1D or 2D texture and then use it in your fragment shader.

You can load data into your texture directly from a typed array, you don't need to create an image first, see [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048238/347857).

With too many uniforms you can easily run into issues on some GPUs. See [webglstats.com](http://webglstats.com/) for some typical limits on the number of uniforms, specifically MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS and MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS.

Comment: @IterAtor I updated my answer, you can load typed arrays directly into a texture.