# Create WebGL texture out of multiple RGBA values

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl, rgba

I am creating a WebGL texture out of one RGBA value based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38668764/6609337) answer, and was wondering how to create one based off of multiple RGBA values.

For this array,

```
var textureData = new Uint8Array([128, 128, 0, 255]);
```

I tried to add additional values for another RGBA value, but nothing changed. For reference, I will have 262,144 RGBA values, if that makes a difference.

Thank you!

Comment: It isn't very clear what is it you're after. You want to create a texture bigger than one pixel, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/) The signature for `gl.texImage2D` is

```
gl.texImage2D(
  target,          // TEXTURE_2D or TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP
  level,           // mip level 0 to n
  internalFormat,  // must match `format` below in WebGL 1.0
  width,           // width of `data` in pixels
  height,          // height of `data` in pixels
  border,          // must always be 0 in WebGL
  format,          // gl.RGBA, gl.RGB, gl.ALPHA, gl.LUMINANCE, ...
  type,            // gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...
  data);           // your data which is width * height pixels
```

Example 3x2

```
// here's 3x2 RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE pixels
var data = new Uint8Array([
  255, 0, 0, 255,      255, 255, 0, 255,    0, 255, 0, 255,
  0, 255, 255, 255,    0, 0, 255, 255,      255, 255, 255, 255,
]);
var level = 0;
var width = 3;
var height = 2;
var format = gl.RGBA;
var type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
var internalFormat = format;
var border = 0;
var target = gl.TEXTURE_2D;

gl.texImage2D(
  target,          // TEXTURE_2D or TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP
  level,           // mip level 0 - n
  internalFormat,  // must match `format` below in WebGL 1.0
  width,           // width of `data` in pixels
  height,          // height of `data` in pixels
  border,          // must always be 0 in WebGL
  format,          // gl.RGBA, gl.RGB, gl.ALPHA, gl.LUMINANCE, ...
  type,            // gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...
  data);           // your data which is width * height pixels
```

There's also `gl.texSubImage2D` if you want to update a smaller portion of a larger texture.

Example:

```js
var vs = `
void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 100.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;
var fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D texture;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord);
}
`;
var gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");
document.body.appendChild(gl.canvas);
var program = twgl.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);
gl.useProgram(program);

// here's 3x2 RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE pixels
var data = new Uint8Array([
  255, 0, 0, 255,      255, 255, 0, 255,    0, 255, 0, 255,
  0, 255, 255, 255,    0, 0, 255, 255,      200, 200, 200, 255,
]);
var level = 0;
var width = 3;
var height = 2;
var format = gl.RGBA;
var type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
var internalFormat = format;
var border = 0;
var target = gl.TEXTURE_2D;

var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(target, texture);
gl.texImage2D(
  target,          // TEXTURE_2D or TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP
  level,           // 0 to n (mip level)
  internalFormat,  // must match `format` below in WebGL 1.0
  width,           // width of `data` in pixels
  height,          // height of `data` in pixels
  border,          // must always be 0 in WebGL
  format,          // gl.RGBA, gl.RGB, gl.ALPHA, gl.LUMINANCE, ...
  type,            // gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...
  data);           // your data which is width * height pixels

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If your dimensions are not powers-of-2 in both dimensions [you need to set filtering and wrapping appropriately](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html).